My First Zig Library: SuperZIG IO  (Input/Output Handling Library)
I’ve recently completed my very first library in Zig, SuperZIG IO, designed to simplify input and output handling. The library provides utilities for console input/output, event listening (like key presses), and aims to offer cross-platform support (Windows, Linux, and macOS).
Here are some of the key features:

Input Handling: Read user inputs with options for customization.
Output Formatting: Output text with formatting capabilities.
Event Listening: Listen to system key press events in real-time.

I’d love to hear your feedback on:

The library’s overall design and structure.
Code readability and maintainability.
Performance optimization tips (especially for cross-platform compatibility).
Ideas for additional features or improvements.

You can find the repo (source code) on GitHub :
SuperZIG IO Repository

SOURCE CODE v0.0.1

io.zig
  const       std                         = @import("std");
  const       builtin                     = @import("builtin");
  const       typesFile                   = @import("./types/_.zig");



  /// Alias for io library types.
  pub const   types                       = typesFile;

  /// Global buffer for General purposes.
  var         g_buff_1024 : [1024]u8      = undefined;



  /// Outputs a simple message followed by a newline.
  pub inline fn out
  ( comptime _msg: []const u8 ) 
  !void 
  {
      try outWith(_msg ++ "\n", .{});
  }

  /// Outputs a formatted message to the console.
  pub inline fn outWith
  ( comptime _fmt: []const u8, _args: anytype ) 
  !void 
  {
      try nosuspend std.io.getStdOut().writer().print(_fmt, _args);
  }

  /// Outputs a simple message followed by a newline to a specific writer.
  pub inline fn outWriter
  ( comptime _msg: []const u8, _writer: anytype ) 
  !void 
  {
      try _writer.print("{s}", .{_msg});
  }

  /// Outputs a formatted message followed by a newline to a specific writer.
  pub inline fn outWriterWith
  ( comptime _fmt: []const u8, _args: anytype, _writer: anytype ) 
  !void 
  {
      try _writer.print(_fmt, _args);
  }



  /// Reads input from the user until a newline character is encountered.
  pub inline fn in
  () 
  ![]const u8 
  {
      const l_res = try std.io.getStdIn().reader().readUntilDelimiterOrEof(&g_buff_1024, '\n');
      return l_res orelse unreachable;
  }

  /// Reads input from the user until a newline character is encountered using custom buffer.
  pub inline fn inBuff
  ( _buff: []u8 )
  !void
  {
      // set zeros (maybe set all buffer to zeros using std ?)
      for (_buff) |*l_byte|
      {
          l_byte.* = 0;
      }

      _ = try std.io.getStdIn().reader().readUntilDelimiterOrEof(_buff, '\n');
  }

  /// Displays a message and waits for the user to respond.
  pub inline fn ask
  ( comptime _msg: []const u8 ) 
  ![]const u8 
  {
      try         out (_msg);
      return try  in  ();
  }

  /// Displays a message and waits for the user to respond using custom buffer.
  pub inline fn askBuff
  ( comptime _msg: []const u8, _buff: []u8 ) 
  !void
  {
      try out     (_msg);
      try inBuff  (_buff);
  }



  /// Listens for key input.
  pub inline fn once
  ( _call: anytype ) 
  !void 
  {
      if (builtin.os.tag == .windows) 
      {
          return @import("./func/on/windows.zig").once(_call);
      } 

      else if (builtin.os.tag == .linux) 
      {
          return @import("./func/on/linux.zig").once(_call);
      } 

      else 
      {
          try outWith("OS not supported : {}\n", .{builtin.os.tag});
          unreachable;
      }
  }

  /// Listens for key input until the condition is met.
  pub inline fn on
  ( _cond: anytype, _call: anytype ) 
  !void 
  {
      if (builtin.os.tag == .windows) 
      {
          return @import("./func/on/windows.zig").on(_cond, _call);
      } 

      else if (builtin.os.tag == .linux) 
      {
          return @import("./func/on/linux.zig").on(_cond, _call);
      } 

      else 
      {
          try outWith("OS not supported : {}\n", .{builtin.os.tag});
          unreachable;
      }
  }



  /// Clears the terminal(Screen).
  pub inline fn cls
  () 
  !void 
  {
      _ = try out("\x1b[2J\x1b[H");
  }


/types/_.zig
  pub const   MOD_ALT       = 1 << 0;
  pub const   MOD_SHIFT     = 1 << 1;
  pub const   MOD_CTRL      = 1 << 2;

  pub const key = @import("./key.zig").key;


/types/key.zig
  pub const   MOD_ALT       = 1 << 0;
  pub const   MOD_SHIFT     = 1 << 1;
  pub const   MOD_CTRL      = 1 << 2;

  /// Struct to represent key press details.
  pub const key = struct
  {
      pub const State = enum
      {
          None,
          SinglePress,
          DoublePress,
      };

      m_val   : u8    = 0,            // key code
      m_mod   : u3    = 0,            // modifier keys (ctrl, alt, shift)
      m_state : State = State.None,   // press state 

      /// Returns the press state.
      pub inline fn state
      (_self: *const key) 
      State
      {
          if(_self.m_state == State.None)
          {
              const isSinglePress = _self.m_mod == 0;

              if(isSinglePress)
              {
                  _self.m_state = State.SinglePress;
              }
              else
              {
                  _self.m_state = State.DoublePress;
              }
          }

          return _self.m_state;
      }

      /// Returns the key code.
      pub inline fn get
      (_self: *const key) 
      u8 
      {
          return _self.m_val;
      }

      /// Returns a character representation of the key.
      pub inline fn char
      (_self: *const key) 
      u8 
      {
          return switch (_self.m_mod)
          {
              4      =>
              {
                  // ctrl 
                  return '@' + _self.m_val;
              },

              5      =>
              {
                  // alt + ctrl 
                  return '@' + _self.m_val;
              },

              else    =>
              {
                  // others
                  return _self.m_val;
              },
          };
      }

      /// Returns a string representation of the modifiers.
      pub inline fn mod
      (_self: *const key) 
      [] const u8 
      {
          return switch (_self.m_mod)
          {
              0       => "none"           ,
              1       => "alt"            ,
              2       => "shift"          ,
              3       => "alt + shift"    ,
              4       => "ctrl"           ,
              5       => "alt + ctrl"     ,
              else    => "unknown"        ,
          };
      }

      /// Returns true if the Alt modifier key was pressed.
      pub inline fn alt
      (_self: *const key)
      bool
      {
          return (_self.m_mod & MOD_ALT) != 0;
      }

      /// Returns true if the Ctrl modifier key was pressed.
      pub inline fn ctrl
      (_self: *const key)
      bool
      {
          return (_self.m_mod & MOD_CTRL) != 0;
      }

      // Returns true if the Shift modifier key was pressed.
      pub inline fn 
      shift(_self: *const key)
      bool
      {
          return (_self.m_mod & MOD_SHIFT) != 0;
      }

      /// Returns count of pressed keys.
      pub inline fn count
      (_self: *const key)
      u8
      {
          var m_count : u8 = 1;

          if (_self.alt())     m_count += 1;
          if (_self.ctrl())    m_count += 1;
          if (_self.shift())   m_count += 1;

          return m_count;
      }
  };


func/on/windows.zig
  const   std                     = @import("std");
  const   loop                    = @import("../../libs/loop.zig");
  const   types                   = @import("../../types/_.zig");

  const   windowsH                = @cImport
  ({
      @cInclude("windows.h");                             // Windows API definitions for handling keyboard input and system events.
  });

  const g_State                   = types.key.State;      // Alias for key press state enumeration.

  // Virtual key codes for common keys
  const VK_LSHIFT                 = 0xA0;
  const VK_RSHIFT                 = 0xA1;
  const VK_LCONTROL               = 0xA2;
  const VK_RCONTROL               = 0xA3;
  const VK_LMENU                  = 0xA4;
  const VK_RMENU                  = 0xA5;

  // Flags representing modifier key states (Ctrl, Shift, Alt)
  const LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED         = 0x0008;
  const RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED        = 0x0004;
  const LEFT_SHIFT_PRESSED        = 0x0010;
  const RIGHT_SHIFT_PRESSED       = 0x0020;
  const LEFT_ALT_PRESSED          = 0x0002;
  const RIGHT_ALT_PRESSED         = 0x0001;

  // Maximum allowed delay between key presses to be considered as double press
  const MAX_KEYPRESS_DELAY : f64  = 1.0;


  /// Listen for a single key press and invoke the provided callback function
  pub inline fn once
  ( _call: anytype ) 
  !void
  {
      try Logic.Core( _call, windowsH.GetStdHandle(windowsH.STD_INPUT_HANDLE) );
  }

  /// Listen for key input until the specified condition is met and invoke the callback function
  pub inline fn on
  ( _cond: anytype, _call: anytype ) 
  !void
  {
      try loop.untilWith( _cond, Logic.Core, .{ _call, windowsH.GetStdHandle(windowsH.STD_INPUT_HANDLE) } );
  }


  const Logic = struct
  {
      var g_lastKeyTime   : f64       = 0.0;              // Stores the timestamp of the last key press
      var g_lastKey       : u8        = 0;                // Stores the last pressed key
      var g_state         : g_State   = g_State.None;     // Stores the current key press state (SinglePress/DoublePress)

      /// Core function to handle key input and invoke the callback function
      inline fn Core
      ( _call: anytype, _hConsole: anytype )
      !void
      {
          var l_inputRecord   : windowsH.INPUT_RECORD     = undefined;
          var l_bytesRead     : u32                       = 0;

          while(true)
          {
              // Read the console input event (key press)
              _ = windowsH.ReadConsoleInputA(_hConsole, &l_inputRecord, 1, &l_bytesRead);

              if (l_inputRecord.EventType == windowsH.KEY_EVENT and l_inputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown != 0)
              {
                  const l_key         = l_inputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
                  const l_currentTime = @as(f64, @floatFromInt(std.time.timestamp()));

                  // Check the time between the current and last key press
                  if (l_currentTime - g_lastKeyTime <= MAX_KEYPRESS_DELAY)
                  {
                      // If the time between presses is less than the allowed threshold, treat as double press
                      g_state         = g_State.DoublePress;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      // Otherwise, treat as single press
                      g_state         = g_State.SinglePress;
                  }

                  g_lastKeyTime       = l_currentTime;        // Update the timestamp of the last key press
                  g_lastKey           = l_key;                // Update the last pressed key

                  const l_modifiers   = Help.detectMods();    // Detect the modifier keys (Shift, Ctrl, Alt)

                  // If the key pressed is 0 (no valid key), ignore
                  if (l_key == 0)
                  {
                      return;
                  }

                  // Create a key object with the key value, modifiers, and key press state
                  const l_res         = types.key
                  {
                      .m_val          = Help.getKeyValue(l_key),
                      .m_mod          = l_modifiers,
                      .m_state        = g_state,
                  };

                  // Call the provided callback function with the key object
                  try _call(l_res);

                  break;
              }
          }
      }

      const Help = struct
      {
          inline fn
          getKeyValue(key: u8) u8
          {
              return key;

              // // Printable character
              // if (std.ascii.isPrint(key))
              // {
              //     return key;
              // }

              // // Handle non-printable key
              // else
              // {
              //     return key;
              // }
          }

          /// Detect the state of modifier keys (Shift, Ctrl, Alt)
          inline fn 
          detectMods
          ( ) 
          u3
          {
              var l_modifiers : u3 = 0;

              // Check if Shift key (either left or right) is pressed
              if (checkKeyState(windowsH.VK_LSHIFT) & 0x8000 != 0 or checkKeyState(windowsH.VK_RSHIFT) & 0x8000 != 0)
              {
                  l_modifiers |= 1 << 1;                  // Set the Shift modifier
              }

              // Check if Ctrl key (either left or right) is pressed and there's a valid key press
              if (checkKeyState(windowsH.VK_LCONTROL) & 0x8000 != 0 or checkKeyState(windowsH.VK_RCONTROL) & 0x8000 != 0)
              {
                  if (g_lastKey != 0)
                  {
                      l_modifiers |= 1 << 2;              // Set the Ctrl modifier
                  }
              }

              // Check if Alt key (either left or right) is pressed and there's a valid key press
              if (checkKeyState(windowsH.VK_LMENU) & 0x8000 != 0 or checkKeyState(windowsH.VK_RMENU) & 0x8000 != 0)
              {
                  if (g_lastKey != 0)
                  {
                      l_modifiers |= 1 << 0;              // Set the Alt modifier
                  }
              }

              return l_modifiers;                         // Return the detected modifiers
          }

          /// Get the current state of a key based on its virtual key code
          inline fn 
          checkKeyState
          ( _keyCode: i32 ) 
          i32
          {
              return windowsH.GetKeyState(_keyCode);      // Return the key state (pressed or not)
          }
      };
  };


func/on/linux.zig
  const   std                     = @import("std");
  const   loop                    = @import("../../libs/loop.zig");
  const   types                   = @import("../../types/_.zig");

  const   linuxH                  = @cImport
  ({
      @cInclude("termios.h");                             // Termios library for terminal I/O settings
      @cInclude("unistd.h");                              // POSIX operating system API (e.g., read, tcsetattr)
  });

  const   g_ts                    = linuxH.termios;
  const   g_tS                    = linuxH.struct_termios;


  // variables to hold the old/new terminal settings
  var     g_oldSettings : g_tS    = undefined;
  var     g_newSettings : g_ts    = undefined;

  // variables to hold the key input
  var     g_keyBuffer   : [3]u8   = undefined;
  var     g_bytesRead   : isize   = undefined;


  /// Listen for key input
  pub inline fn once
  ( _call: anytype ) 
  !void
  {
      try Logic.Core( _call );
  }

  /// Listen for key input until the condition is met
  pub inline fn on
  ( _cond: anytype, _call: anytype ) 
  !void
  {
      try loop.untilWith( _cond, Logic.Core, .{ _call } );
  }


  const Logic = struct
  {
      /// The entry point of our logic !
      inline fn Core
      ( _call: anytype )
      !void
      {
          Help.init();

          // Read key input
          g_bytesRead = linuxH.read(0, &g_keyBuffer, @sizeOf(@TypeOf(g_keyBuffer)));

          if (g_bytesRead > 0)
          {
              const l_res: types.key = Help.detectMods(g_keyBuffer[0..], g_bytesRead);

              try _call(l_res);
          }
          else
          {
              // try _call(types.key{ .key = 0, .character = 0, .modifiers = 0, });
              unreachable;
          }

          Help.reset();
      }

      const Help = struct
      {
          /// Restore old terminal settings to prevent permanent changes.
          inline fn reset
          ()
          void
          {
              _ = linuxH.tcsetattr(0, linuxH.TCSAFLUSH, &g_oldSettings);
          }

          /// Setup the new terminal settings.
          inline fn init
          ()
          void
          {
              // Cleanup the buffer
              g_keyBuffer[0..].* = @as([3]u8, std.mem.zeroes([3]u8));

              // Get current terminal settings and store in 'oldSettings'
              _ = linuxH.tcgetattr(0, &g_oldSettings);

              // Copy the current settings to 'newSettings'
              g_newSettings = g_oldSettings;


              // Disable canonical mode (no buffering, no waiting for Enter key to submit input)
              g_newSettings.c_lflag &= @as(c_uint, ~@as(c_uint, linuxH.ICANON));  // Clear the ICANON flag to disable canonical mode


              // Disable echoing characters (input characters will not be displayed on the terminal)
              g_newSettings.c_lflag &= @as(c_uint, ~@as(c_uint, linuxH.ECHO));    // Clear the ECHO flag to disable character echoing


              // Set minimum number of characters to 1 (we don’t need to wait for Enter key)
              g_newSettings.c_cc[linuxH.VMIN] = 1;                                // Set the VMIN control character to 1 to require at least 1 character


              // Set timeout to 0 (no wait time for input)
              g_newSettings.c_cc[linuxH.VTIME] = 0;                               // Set the VTIME control character to 0 to disable wait time


              // Set the new terminal settings
              if (linuxH.tcsetattr(0, linuxH.TCSAFLUSH, &g_newSettings) != 0) 
              {
                  // Register the cleanup function to restore terminal settings on program exit
                  defer reset();
              }
          }

          // Function to detect modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift)
          inline fn detectMods
          ( _keyBuffer: []const u8, _bytesRead: isize )
          types.key
          {
              var l_res = types.key
              {
                  .m_val      = 0,
                  .m_mod      = 0,
                  .m_state    = types.key.State.None
              };

              if (_bytesRead == 0)
              {
                  return l_res;
              }

              // Alt key detection
              if (_keyBuffer[0] == 0x1B)
              {
                  l_res.m_mod |= types.MOD_ALT;

                  if (_bytesRead > 1) {
                      l_res.m_val = _keyBuffer[1];

                      if (std.ascii.isUpper(_keyBuffer[1]))
                      {
                          l_res.m_mod |= types.MOD_SHIFT;
                      }

                      if (_keyBuffer[1] >= 0x00 and _keyBuffer[1] <= 0x1F)
                      {
                          l_res.m_mod |= types.MOD_CTRL;
                      }
                  }

                  return l_res;
              }

              // Ctrl key detection
              if (_keyBuffer[0] >= 0x00 and _keyBuffer[0] <= 0x1F)
              {
                  l_res.m_mod |= types.MOD_CTRL;
                  l_res.m_val = _keyBuffer[0];

                  return l_res;
              }

              // Shift detection
              if (std.ascii.isUpper(_keyBuffer[0]))
              {
                  l_res.m_mod |= types.MOD_SHIFT;
              }

              l_res.m_val = getKeyValue(_keyBuffer[0]);

              return l_res;
          }  

          inline fn
          getKeyValue(key: u8) u8
          {
              return key;

              // // Printable character
              // if (std.ascii.isPrint(key))
              // {
              //     return key;
              // }

              // // Handle non-printable key
              // else
              // {
              //     return key;
              // }
          }
      };
  };



Any thoughts, tips, or constructive criticism are greatly appreciated.
SuperZIG IO Repository
